# $n\log_2(n)\in\Omega\left(10^3n\right)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I am struggling with a new topic in my discrete math class.
I must show that

$$n\log_2(n)\in\Omega\left(10^3n\right)$$

A detailed explanation will be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

First note that
$$f(x)\in\Omega(g(x))\ \mbox{as}\ x\to\infty$$
If
$$\limsup_{x\to\infty}\left\vert\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right\vert\gt 0$$
So now we have
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\vert\frac{n\log_2(n)}{10^3n}\right\vert$$
$$=\frac1{10^3}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\vert\log_2(n)\right\vert$$
I think you can take it from here. The basic idea is to show that the above limit is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $\Omega(10^3n) = \Omega(n)$.

Comment: I think I solved it but in my opinion, it's incorrect. I just wrote that lim of that two fractions, when n tends to infinity, is plus infinity and this proves the questions. What do you think about this?

Comment: @NikaChelidze, add your solution as an answer

Comment: So is it correct?